# What is the appropriate (easiest) way to connect driver vers 3.0.17 to Android Async activity

Tags: sql-server, android-studio, jdbc, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

The logic should be correct for the actual Query but I keep getting the following error:

```
05-02 00:27:39.709 12213-12753/com.example.jordan.myapplication E/error here 3 :: Invalid name: libs/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar
```

I did, at the time receiving the above in logcat, have the drier included in libs but as a module. I had previously to the error, at one point, have it set in libs but I had since taken it out. I must have left something in their. However, my gradle dependencies were set to include it as a module:

```
compile project('mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar')
```

i have since the error added the driver to the library, deleted the module and reset my dependence as:

```
    compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar')
```

Computer has frozen. Restarting computer and then testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting a : at the beginning of 'mysql-connctor-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar' Still not able to get information through the queries I wrote, however, this solves the technical question.